# Save holiday title (tips)

Tags: php, api

I really have no idea on how can I save the title for each holiday into the database. 
The `$msia_holidays_url` is retrieve from google calendar API for 2 years. My current code, it's only save　date and no title.

I did try to change `$JapHolidays[] = $date;` into `$MalHolidays[$date] = $title;` it save the title and date, but the problem with that is some date(s) like 2014-01-01 is not save into the database. I really wonder why. Please help me.

```
if($results=file_get_contents($msia_holidays_url)) {
    $results = json_decode($results, true);
    $MalHolidays = array();
    foreach($results['feed']['entry'] as $val) {
        $date = $val['gd$when'][0]['startTime']; 
        $title = $val['title']['$t']; 
        $MalHolidays [] = $date; 
    }
    ksort($MalHolidays); 
    foreach ($MalHolidays as $key => $value) {
        $sql =  "INSERT INTO mtb_holiday (date, name, remark) ".
                    "VALUES ('".$value."','".$key."','2')";
        mysql_query($sql);
    }
    print_r ($MalHolidays);
}
```

Comment: according to that code $MalHolidays is empty

Answer (score 0):

I am not clear what you want to do but if you want to insert the date and title of all the holidays you receive from $msia_holidays_url then this code should work.

```
if($results=file_get_contents($msia_holidays_url)) {
$results = json_decode($results, true);
$MalHolidays = array();
foreach($results['feed']['entry'] as $val) {
    $date = $val['gd$when'][0]['startTime']; 
    $title = $val['title']['$t'];
    $sql =  "INSERT INTO mtb_holiday (date, name, remark) ".
    "VALUES ('".$date."','".$title."','2')";
    mysql_query($sql);
    $JapHolidays[] = $date; 
}
}
```